# Flash CS5 Actionscript 3.0 Does not go to random frame

Tags: flash, variables, random, frame

I am pretty new to Flash and I'm making a topography quiz for on my website.

The goal of my topography quiz is to get 72 questions of citynames in a random order. I already made this, but the problem is that, because the order is random, questions can come back. So if you finished a question it must not come back again later. I thought I would solve this problem by giving a variable to every frame which all have the value "2" at the start. If you go to a frame and you type in the correct cityname the variable of that frame will turn "1". If you typed an incorrect answer the variable will turn "0". At the start of every frame I wrote: "if(city01 == 2){" so if you never had that question before you will just get the question. If not you will get to the next (random) frame.

At the first frame I defined the variables:

```
var input:String;
var randomnumber:int;

var city01:int = 2;
var city02:int = 2;
var city03:int = 2;
var city04:int = 2;
etc. etc. etc.
```

Here is an example of the code of a question frame:

```
    stop();
if(city26 == 2){


okButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, okClickcity26);

function okClickcity26(event:MouseEvent):void{
    input = textbox.text;
    if(input == "Dakar"){
        city26 = 1; 
    }else{
        city26 = 0; 
    }

    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+73-3))+3;
    gotoAndStop(randomnumber);
}
}else{
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+73-3))+3;
    gotoAndStop(randomnumber);
    }
```

Flash does change the variables to "1" or "2", but does also just shows the question and not go to a next frame.

So Flash executes the code at the end:

```
    else{
randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+73-3))+3;
gotoAndStop(randomnumber);
}
```

But does not go to that random frame...

Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

**This is my first question on a forum, so I hoped I explained my problem good, so you can help me. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer a different solution: perhaps you could use an array of question ids/ints (which it seems like you may already have), and then after shuffling them, just pop off the ids one by one to get no duplicates?

Perhaps this can be easier then trying to keep track of each state of each question, then checking upon random number generation. Just t be sure, I see the problem as you want to get to individual questions in a random order, but with no duplicates after they've been seen.

---

---

**Edit: Added code example of using an array**

An array (in this case) can act as a dynamic list of question ids (numbers) in which you access via index or a number of methods. So, you can then associate those numbers/ids to a frame and jump to them.

They are actually quite common in languages (though they may be called different) as well as being quite useful. In your original code, I would have use a single array with a length of 72 to hold my values, instead of having to define 72 variables one by one (city01, city02, city03, etc...).

I highly recommend you read up about them in actionscript 3 (since that is what you are using): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Example of using an array in code to show what I mean in my original answer:

```
// create an array called "questionIds"
var questionIds:Array = new Array();

// using a loop to add ints 0 to 71 to the array
for(var counter:int = 0; counter < 72; counter++){
    questionIds.push(counter);
}

// the array contains the numbers 0 to 71 in order now, shuffle them in to a random order
trace("Preshuffled array: {"+ questionIds +"}");

questionIds.sort(function (inputA:int, inputB:int):int {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1);
});

trace("\nShuffled array: "+ questionIds +"}");

//to get a int from the array, can use pop() method, which removes and returns the last element on the array
// since that number is removed, it will never appear again
var currentId:int = questionIds.pop();

// can keep calling pop() method on the array to return the next last number
// what you do with the value of "currentId" is up to you -however you go to your question in your quiz
currentId = questionIds.pop();
trace(currentId);

// you can also check how many elements are left in the array by checking the length of it:
trace(questionIds.length); // which should be 70 left now as it started with 72 and 2 items were pop()'ed off

// when it hits 0, there are no more items left in the array, (calling pop() will then return "undefined")
if(questionIds.length == 0){
    trace("no more items left");
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer.
I'm not that familiar with arrays, but do you know whether it is possible to let every part of the array run a frame?